# Standard numbers for responsive layout

Tags: website-design, responsive-design, css

What are the (standard) numbers to work with, when making css responsive layout?

```
@media screen and (min-width: px) {
    /* Mobile */
}
@media screen and (min-width: px) {
    /* Tablet */
}
@media screen and (min-width: px) {
    /* Desktop */
}
```

And

```
@media screen and (max-width: px) {
    /* Mobile */
}
@media screen and (max-width: px) {
    /* Tablet */
}
@media screen and (max-width: px) {
    /* Desktop */
}
```

Comment: Why you don't use a responsive HTML5/CSS3 FrameWork like Twitter's Bootstrap?

Comment: @alessadro I can, but I want to do it this way.

Comment: Well, check out this link, there are more than you think, if you want be specific by devices (maybe you want it, because you are doing from scratch)> https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Material design has a very complete section on [Responsive UI layouts](https://material.io/guidelines/layout/responsive-ui.html#responsive-ui-breakpoints) with numbers.

According to it the screen sizes in dp would go:

- xsmall: 0 - 600
- small: 600 - 960
- medium: 960 - 1280
- large: 1280 - 1920
- xlarge: 1920+

[image]